# Running tests with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-boot, mockito

So I'm trying to test Spring boot MVC app that I wrote:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = PetClinicApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class OwnerControllerTests {
    @Mock
    private OwnerService ownerService;

    @InjectMocks
    private OwnerController ownerController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(ownerController).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testOwnerList() throws Exception{
        List<Owner> owners = new ArrayList<>();
        owners.add(new Owner());
        owners.add(new Owner());

        when(ownerService.getAll()).thenReturn((List<Owner>) owners);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/ownerList"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("ownerList"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("ownerList", List.class));

    }

}
```

And im gettin in line

```
when(ownerService.getAll()).thenReturn((List<Owner>) owners);
```

in debugger mode ownerService=null
this is OwnerService.class

```
@Transactional
public Collection<Owner> getAll() {
    return ownerDao.getAll();
}
```

this method should return list of Owner.class objects

owner controller snippet

```
@Controller
public class OwnerController {

    @Autowired
    private OwnerService ownerService;

    @RequestMapping("/addOwner")
    public String addOwner(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("Owner", new Owner());
        return "addOwner";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "addOwner.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addOwnerDo(@Valid @ModelAttribute(value = "Owner") Owner owner, BindingResult result) {

        if (result.hasErrors())
            return "addOwner";
        ObjectBinder.bind(owner);
        ownerService.add(owner);
        return "redirect:addOwner";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/ownerList")
    public String ownerList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("ownerList", ownerService.getAll());
        return "ownerList";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/ownerList/{id}")
    public String ownerDetails(@PathVariable(value = "id") int id, Model model) {
        Owner owner = ownerService.get(id);
        model.addAttribute("owner", owner);
        return "ownerDetail";
    }

    // to refactor
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ownerList/{id}.do")
    public String ownerDetailsDo(@ModelAttribute(value = "owner") Owner owner, BindingResult result,
            @RequestParam(value = "action") String action, Model model) {


        switch (action) {
        case "update":
            ObjectBinder.bind(owner);
            ownerService.update(owner);
            return "ownerDetail";
        case "delete":
            ownerService.remove(owner.getId());
            model.addAttribute("ownerList", ownerService.getAll());
            return "ownerList";
        }
        model.addAttribute("owner", owner);
        return "ownerDetail";
    }



}
```

Comment: Show us OwnerController

Comment: Note that you should now favor the mockito JUnit rule instead of invoking `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` it performs more checks on mockito mocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to annotate your setup method with `@Before` such that mockito do not create and inject the mocks, try this:

```
@Before
public void setup(){
   ...
}
```